# Prevent form submissions till ajax responds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On form submission a function `validate()` is executed and functions checks  user input validity.

Validation criteria includes an ajax that checks if entered email is already registered or not.

The problem is that before the ajax responds, it is executed other validations and form is submitted, failing always the check for email record uniqueness.

Is there a way where i can ensure that the function `validate()` is **executed sequentially** or the code below the Ajax call is executed after it responds?

Thanks in advance.

```
function validate(){
    var comma_regex = /^\w(\s*,?\s*\w)*$/,
        alpha_regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/,
        email_reg_exp = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/ ;

    var email = document.getElementById("email").value,
        other_indus = document.getElementById("other_indus").value,
        other_sub_indus = document.getElementById("other_sub_indus").value,
        other_stage = document.getElementById("other_stage").value;

    var  flagvalue = 0 ;

    if((email !=='')){
      if(!email_reg_exp.test(email)){
        $('#email').css('border', 'solid 1px red');
        $('#email_span').html('<h5 style="color:red;font-size:10px">Please enter a valid Email ID </h5>');

        flagvalue = 1;

      }else{
        $.ajax({
          url : "investor_email_check",
          type: "POST",
          data : 'email='+email,

          success: function(data){
            if(data == '1'){ // failure: data already exists

              $('#email').css('border', 'solid 1px red');
              $('#email_span').html('<h5 style="color:red;font-size:10px">Email ID is already registered </h5>');

              flagvalue = 1 ;

            } else {
              $('#email').css('border', '1px solid #ccc');
              $('#email_span').html('');
            }
          }
        });

      }    
    } else {
      $('#email').css('border', 'solid 1px red');
      $('#email_span').html('<h5 style="color:red;font-size:10px">Please enter a  Email ID </h5>');

      flagvalue = 1 ;
    }



     if((other_indus != '')&& !(comma_regex.test(other_indus))){
       $('#other_indus').css('border', 'solid 1px red');
       $('#other_indus_span').html('<h5 style="color:red;font-size:10px">Please enter a valid format</h5>');

       flagvalue = 1 ;
     } else {
       $('#other_indus').css('border', '1px solid #ccc');
       $('#other_indus_span').html('');
     }

     if((other_sub_indus != '')&& !(comma_regex.test(other_sub_indus))){
       $('#other_sub_indus').css('border', 'solid 1px red');
       $('#other_sub_indus_span').html('<h5 style="color:red;font-size:10px">Please enter a valid format</h5>');

       flagvalue = 1 ;
     } else {
       $('#other_sub_indus').css('border', '1px solid #ccc');
       $('#other_sub_indus_span').html('');
     }

     if((other_stage != '')&& !(comma_regex.test(other_stage))){
       $('#other_stage').css('border', 'solid 1px red');
       $('#other_stage_span').html('<h5 style="color:red;font-size:10px">Please enter a valid format</h5>');

       flagvalue = 1 ;
     } else {
       $('#other_stage').css('border', '1px solid #ccc');
       $('#other_stage_span').html('');
     }

     if(flagvalue == 1){
       return false;
     } else {
       return true ;
     }  
   }
```

Comment: _"And we end up having a duplicate entry for email"_ When you've got this initial problem fixed, you need to also fix this bit on the server.  You can't rely on the client executing the duplicate check and not submitting a duplicate email account - any verification you do client side needs to be redone on the server also.

Comment: yes will also do that  @JamesThorpe

Comment: @morels code included

Comment: Does "investor_email_check" save the email if valid? From the provided code it is not clear the actions sequence you described. I suggest to redesign the model first.

Comment: no it just checks whether email exist or not ,if exists it returns 1 else 0

Answer (score -1):

if you are using jQuery, try this

```
$('#submit_button').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $.post(url_of_validation, params, function(data) {
   //if success
   $('#form').submit();
 });
});
```

Comment: what if user submits by keyboard?

Comment: you mean when the user hits ENTER on keyboard? on my case it still work

Comment: How can it? Button click never occurs

Comment: because originally the button is a submit type. and submit type buttons are triggered when pressing enter key inside the form or by just simply click onto it. so when you hit ENTER key the click event of that submit type button will be triggered.

Comment: Hitting Enter does not trigger a `click` event. Will eat my words when you provide demo proving otherwise

Answer (score -2):

add `<form onsubmit="return validate()">`,it force form to run JS and the process of submission done on the basis or return from function. if function return true then it'll submit form otherwise form will not submit

Comment: And how would you use asynchronous method as part of `validate()`?